# postfixでホスト名を隠したい

Tags: postfix, dovecot

postfixを使用し、メールの設定をしています。 現在以下の作業が完了しております。

> ・postfixのインストール  
>   ・main.cf , master.cfの設定  
>   ・mailコマンドによる送信テスト 
>   ・webminインストールによるGUI操作の構築

現在サーバ上に作成したアカウントへのメールの送信が確認出来ております。 ただ現在、

> info@mail.example.com

へ送信していおりますがこちらを

> info@example.com

へ送信したいです。
いまのところ、info@example.comへメールを送信するとISPよりエラーUnKnownメッセージが帰ってきます。

Comment: 「info@mail.example.comへ送信している感じ」の「感じ」とはどういう意味でしょうか。たとえば、info@example.comに送信したメールが中継過程でinfo@mail.example.com宛てに変化しているようだが具体的に確認したわけではない、趣旨での「感じ」ですか？曖昧な言葉を使わずに、わかっていること、わかっていないことをはっきり区別して書いた方がよいです。

Comment: 状況はわかりましたので、postconf -nの出力と、master.cfの内容を質問に追記してください

Comment: やりたいこと、やったことの情報が少なすぎ・曖昧すぎます。Postfix で example.com ドメインのメールを受けるようにしたいということですか。Postfix でそのように設定し、該当する DNS のリソースレコード (MX あるいは A あるいは AAAA) を Postfix 稼働ホストに向けるだけです。Dovecot を MDA として利用したいなら Dovecot の設定も必要です。

Comment: MXレコードを追加し、SMTP25ポートを開放し設定が完了しました。 ありがとうございました。

Comment: マルチポストです。https://teratail.com/questions/26140

Answer (score 2):

ネットワーク構成の説明がないので一般論しか書けませんが、この質問の範疇であれば Postfix の設定とか以前に、取得されたドメインの DNS の MX レコードを設定する必要があるのではないかと思われます。

[ASCII.jp：メールを支えるドメイン名とDNSの仕組み (1/2)｜電子メールの秘密](http://ascii.jp/elem/000/000/432/432823/)

> 通常のメールアドレスには、宛先のユーザー（のメールボックス）が所属する組織を表わす「ドメイン名」が含まれている。ただ、このドメイン名は、組織などのグループに付けられる名前で、特定のサーバを示すわけではない。たとえばWebサーバであれば「tech.ascii.jp」のように、ホスト名の形で通信相手を特定する。これと同様に、本来であればメールの宛先であるメールサーバのホスト名を指定するべきである。もちろん、メールアドレスに「@mta.biglobe.ne.jp」といった具合に、メールサーバの名前（に見える情報）を追加しているISPもある。しかし、企業などでは「@ascii.co.jp」のように、ドメイン名だけの表記が多い。では、どのようにしてドメイン名からメールサーバを特定しているのだろうか。結論からいえば、これはDNS（Domain Name System）のおかげである。

Comment: MXレコードを追加し、SMTP25ポートを開放し設定が完了しました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 回答に「承認済み」のマークをして下さい。今までの質問全てが、承認済みになっていません。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers